# How to create XML file to be read in Python using sublime 3?

Tags: python, xml, amazon-web-services, sublimetext3

I am creating qualification tests in MTurk, for which I am to create two .xml files for the questions and another to evaluate the worker's answers.  I have created the file per AWS' schema but when I pass the .xml file through for python to read, the output is file not found.

I am not sure what I am missing.

```
questions = open(name='question_form.xml', mode='r').read() #passing qual questions
answers = open(name='answerkey.xml', mode='r').read() #passing answerkey
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the output file is not found"?

Comment: I mean the error msg reads as follows:   
TypeError: Required argument 'file' (pos 1) not found

Comment: In Python 2, the first argument to `open()` is `name` to give the name of the file; in Python 3 the first argument is named `file` instead. That argument is in the first position, so based on your message about the argument `file` at position 1 not being found, your problem sounds like you're trying to run Python 2 code with Python 3. Changing `name=` to `file=` would probably solve the problem (though it might cause others).

Comment: Thank you! I actually just figured it out before coming to read your msg but you have explained the 'why', now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the xml package ? :

```
with open('test.xml') as file_to_read:
    root = ET.parse(file_to_read).getroot()
    try :
        print(root)
    except :
        print("could not retrieve value")
```